# How do I assign one color to a specific value in ggplot2 function scale_fill_gradient2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the `geom_tile` function in R to build a heatmap. I am using the `scale_fill_gradient2` function to assign a specific color scale to a column. The issue is that I want to assign the color black to a specific numeric value. Similar to how you can assign a specific color to NA values. Below is a toy dataset that I am using.

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:2,y = 0:3)
df$z <- c(4.80,-0.07,NA,NA,-1.48,1,-3.60,2.93,NA,4.34,NA,1)
```

The code for the plot is the following.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = '#0017FF',
    mid = "white",
    high = '#FF2D00',
    midpoint = 0,
    na.value = "grey50"
  )
```

The plot looks like this.

[image]

This is mostly what I want. However, in the final column of the heatmap where z = 1, I would like the color to be black. So it should look like this instead.

[image]

I want to note that wherever z = 1 in the data, I plan to assign some random number to distinguish it from the rest of the data. I just need to first know how to assign a color to a specific value within the gradient function.

Comment: I'm confused -- how would a gradient have a color in it that the gradient does not have? Are you asking how to modify the gradient so one of the ends is black, or how to make a layer that ignores the gradient, or something else?

Comment: How to essentially make a second scale that ignores the gradient. The first answer below is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by making a new color scale that identifies only the boxes you want to color black.  This can be done with `ggnewscale`.

```r
library(ggnewscale)
library(ggplot2)
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:2,y = 0:3)
df$z <- c(4.80,-0.07,NA,NA,-1.48,1,-3.60,2.93,NA,4.34,NA,1)
df$x <- as.factor(df$x)
df$y <- as.factor(df$y)
df$z2 <- ifelse(df$x == 2 & df$y %in% c(1,3), 1, 0)
df$z2 <- as.factor(df$z2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = '#0017FF',
    mid = "white",
    high = '#FF2D00',
    midpoint = 0,
    na.value = "grey50"
  ) + 
  new_scale_fill() + 
  geom_tile(aes(x,y,fill=z2), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("transparent", "black"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. I never knew about ggnewscale until now :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option that does not require the addition of a new package.

```r
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = '#0017FF',
    mid = "white",
    high = '#FF2D00',
    midpoint = 0,
    na.value = "grey50"
  )
```

To the original plot, *overlay* another `geom_tile` with just the cells you want blacked out.

```r
gg +
  geom_tile(data = ~ subset(., z == 1),
            fill="black", width=1, height=1)
```

[image: grob with select cells blacked out]

As for the use of `data = ~ subset(., z == 1)`:

- the `~`-function allows us to work on whatever data was fed to `ggplot()`, so this is safe to use for instance at the end of a dplyr-pipe where the original data may not have all of the values/attributes we need it to.
- I've used `subset`, it could easily be `dplyr::filter` or `data.table::[` filtering, based on the user needs and original data class. (In fact, `?subset` says that it *"is a convenience function intended for use interactively"*, and for "programming" use it is generally preferred to *"use the standard subsetting functions like `[`"*. Over to you.)
- `z == 1` *might* be fragile if your numbers have high-precision, akin to [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272), https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754. A more robust method might be `abs(z - 1) < 1e-6` or some equally small number to test for tolerance ... but that might be over-engineering, depending on your data.
- As I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77455741/3358272), the trick to laying a second `geom_tile` over the first is to ensure that the tile `width=` and `height=` are identical; while they tend to be safely inferred on the original call, it is imperfect and on this second call it will guess incorrectly due to the reduced data size; this is why I've added `width=1, height=1` to the second call (it would not hurt in the first call, too).

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(x = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L), y = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), z = c(4.8, -0.07, NA, NA, -1.48, 1, -3.6, 2.93, NA, 4.34, NA, 1)), out.attrs = list(dim = structure(3:4, names = c("x", "y")), dimnames = list(x = c("x=0", "x=1", "x=2"), y = c("y=0", "y=1", "y=2", "y=3"))), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is awesome as well. Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to add a legend for the second geom_tile object as well?

Comment: Erm .... that's a bit difficult ... is that just a black square to indicate "something"?

Comment: I think a second `fill`-legend is best done using `ggnewscale`, tbh. Starting with stock `df`, from your original plot add `+ new_scale_fill() + geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill = "something"), show.legend = TRUE, data = ~ subset(., z == 1), width = 1, height = 1) + scale_fill_manual(name = NULL, values = "black")`.