# multiple calls to geom_tile are differently aligned

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was looking at [How do I assign one color to a specific value in ggplot2 function scale_fill_gradient2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77455603/3358272), and one attempt I had was to add a second call to `geom_tile`, but that produces counter-intuitive results.

Q: why does a second call to `geom_tile` using a subset of the original data (otherwise unmodified) shift the tiles?

```r
df <- structure(list(x = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L), y = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), z = c(4.8, -0.07, NA, NA, -1.48, 1, -3.6, 2.93, NA, 4.34, NA, 1)), out.attrs = list(dim = structure(3:4, names = c("x", "y")), dimnames = list(x = c("x=0", "x=1", "x=2"), y = c("y=0", "y=1", "y=2", "y=3"))), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = '#0017FF',
    mid = "white",
    high = '#FF2D00',
    midpoint = 0,
    na.value = "grey50"
  )
```

[image: basic geom_tile plot]

So far so good. Adding a second call to `geom_tile` with filtered data, though, appears to shift the tile centers:

```r
gg + geom_tile(data = df[c(6, 12),])
```

[image: same plot with a second call to geom_tile]

Note: I'm not asking to solve the other question's problem, I'm asking why the second call to `geom_tile` appears to use a different set of limits, such that the tiles are not the same dimensions and are placed on different x/y positions on the existing canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't specify the width or height, geom_tile infers them from the "resolution" of that layer's data. So if one layer sees data arranged where each y is 1 unit apart, but another layer sees data where the y values are 2 units apart, they will be rendered on different grids.

I presume it was set up that way since the underlying data for a plot might range by orders of magnitude, but having `geom_tile` assume a 1 unit width and height will not work well if the data has a resolution of 0.0001 units or 1M units. ggplot2 *does* assume a 1 unit default when the data does not vary in that variable.

The best way to resolve this where the data might have different resolutions in different layers would be to be explicit about the height/width you want.

Compare:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 2, y = c(0,1)), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile(fill = "white", color = "black")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 2, y = c(0,2)), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_tile(fill = "white", color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: So it could be "fixed" by setting those values in the `geom`: `gg + geom_tile(data = df[c(6, 12),], height=1, width=1, fill="orange")`

Comment: My key takeaway: *"infers them from the "resolution" of that layer's data"*. Impeccable, thank you!